# How to resolve DeprecationWarning: "HTTPS policy .. does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS"?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run scrapy and save data into Mongo ,It works but I see there are two DeprecationWarning
Can someone tell me What's this and how should I do?

**DeprecationWarning:  was passed as the HTTPS policy for an Agent, but it does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS.  Since Twisted 14.0, you must pass a provider of IPolicyForHTTPS.
  connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)
DeprecationWarning: `w3lib.html.remove_entities` function is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use `w3lib.html.replace_entities` instead.
  DeprecationWarning**

Comment: This issue is tracked at https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/784 . The other warning should be solved in scrapy master branch (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/928e7f2924811574e788e7083ce5339a5f83379f)

Comment: Sorry,My ability is pool.I don't understand.does it means I should update my scrapy?

Comment: @user2492364 how did you fixed your issue? didn't find anything good on this.